# replace function to replace single quote string

Tags: javascript

I have this string `something='http://example.com/something'` and how can I replace the something=' with nothing?

when I do `str.replace('something='','')` I got syntax error. I tried `str.replace('something=\'','')` and expect to escape the single quote with slash, it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.replace('something='','')` will of course lead to a syntax error.

Try

`str.replace("something='","")`

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is a replacement of `something='` and all ticks (`'`) including the closing one... So you could use this:

```js
var str = "something='http://example.com/something'";

alert(str.replace(/something='(.*)'/, "$1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `str` variable with the returned value since [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method doesn't update the variable.

```
str = str.replace('something=\'', '')
```

---

Although it's better to use double quotes instead of escaping.

```
str = str.replace("something='", '')
```